# Magento 2 checkout_index_index how data is defined

Tags: magento2, checkout

If I refer to this code

```
<item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="target" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id]]></item>
    <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
</item>
```

Can any one explain me what this part does

`<![CDATA[${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id]]`

what is `$.provider` and `$.parentScope` ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you already know what CDATA is.

The code inside called template literal, Magento Core team want to use the ES6 template syntax so they come up with their own code

ES6 syntax:

> `${provider}` -> Magento syntax: ${$.provider}

You can read more here in the devdocs:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_template_literals.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_linking_concept.html

And if you want to dig deeper, check the code in this file:

> lib/web/mage/utils/template.js